# Customizing jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to let users customize pages, let's call them A and B. So basically I want to provide a hyperlink  to a jps page  with big text box where a user should be able to enter any text, html (to appear on page A), with ability to preview it and save.

I haven't really deal with this sort of issues before and would appreciate help on how implement it (examples  and reference  would be very helpful too)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to allow remote users to customize the JSP page, or allow them to enter HTML to be displayed within the (uncustomized) JSP page?

Comment: second one, I want to allow certain user to enter so text that will be part of say welcoming screen....

Comment: In that case, someone should edit the question title.  This is quesion is NOT about customizing JSP pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any kind of web framework(Spring MVC / Struts / Tapestry / etc...)? If you are, they all have tutorials on dealing with user inputs / form submission, so take a look at that. They all differ slightly in how user input is processed so it's impossible to answer this question generically.

If you're not (e.g. this is straight JSP), take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/Forms.jsp).

Basically, what you want to do is to define an HTML form on your **page B** with textarea where user would input custom HTML. When form is submitted, you'll get the text user entered as a request parameter and you can store it somewhere (in the database / flat file / memory / what have you). On your **page A** you'll need to retrieve that text and bind it to request or page scope, you can then display it using `<%= %>` or `<jsp:getProperty>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

To ChssPly76's answer I'd just add that if you're going to provide text entry of html on a web page (or anywhere, really) you're going to want to provide some kind of validation and a mechanism to provide feedback if the html is bad. You might dispense with this for a raw internal tool but anything for public consumption will need it. e.g. what do you do if someone enters

`<b>sometext`

You can deal with this with simple rules that parse away html tags, a preview that lets people know how they're doing so far ala stackoverflow, an rtf input option, or just a validate and if the tags don't balance a big honking "Try again", but you'll want some kind of check that you won't just be putting up broken pages.

Comment: @Steve B: I think you should mention checking for undesirable / malicious content; e.g. nasty javascript, links to malware sites, link spam, and so on.